# incredibly slow app using array of images in a gridview

Tags: android

I have the following little app that displays a grid of photos.  When a photo is pressed/clicked, then a larger version opens up.

Technically, it works.  However, it's very slow in my Android virtual device.  I am also seeing these messages pop-up in the Android Studio logs.

> I/Choreographer: Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too
>   much work on its main thread.

So I must be doing something wrong.

Given the code below, is there a way to "fix" this?

Thanks!

```
package com.zeus.miniapps.photoviewer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ImageGrid extends AppCompatActivity {

    Integer[] ApocImages =  {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4,
                             R.drawable.image5, R.drawable.image6, R.drawable.image7, R.drawable.image8,
                             R.drawable.image9, R.drawable.image10, R.drawable.image11, R.drawable.image12,
                             R.drawable.image13, R.drawable.image14, R.drawable.image15, R.drawable.image16};

    ImageView pic;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_grid);
        GridView grid = findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        final ImageView pic = findViewById(R.id.imgLarge);
        grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        pic.setClickable(true);

        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext( ), "Selected Image " + (position + 1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show( );
                pic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pic.setImageResource(ApocImages[position]);
            }
        });

        pic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pic.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            context = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return ApocImages.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View contentView, ViewGroup parent) {
            pic = new ImageView(context);
            pic.setImageResource(ApocImages[position]);
            pic.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            pic.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(330, 300));
            return pic;
        }

    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of this awesome app in action!

[image]

Comment: Your adapter is very inefficient because you are not following the recommended view holder pattern. E.g. when you scroll, you never reuse your views and you keep creating lots of `ImageView` objects. Only fixing this thing might already solve the issue.

Comment: Here is more information: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling

Comment: As you're loading fullsized images. It will eat huge size of memory. It's better to use `Glide`. It'll automatically resize the image for your view and will cache the images for next time loading. https://github.com/bumptech/glide try it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you loading in your gridview all your images at full size? If yes, that might be the problem and at some point you might even get an outOfMemory. It might also be from the fact that your virtual device does not have enough ram, try it on a device. And about the first issue you might want to create a thumbnail of the image to show in the gridview and to show the fullres only when the user taps on the photo. 
Those are just assumptions no way to be sure of those. You can try to show in your gridview a list with really low res images and see if it gets less laggy. If it does, then it is because of your images that are too big and consuming too much memory. 
I know i explain like shit and if it is anything that you did not understand tell me.

Comment: They are full size, but the largest one is only about 300 kb. All images combined are 2.5 MB.  I checked the available ram on the virtual device and it's 1.5 GBs.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Optimize your images before use it in your gridview,, you can also use image thumbnail.